# socket library poll vs custom poll

Tags: algorithm, sockets

So I was having some (arguably) fun with sockets (in c) and then I came across the problem of asynchronously receiving.

As stated [here](https://daniel.haxx.se/docs/poll-vs-select.html), `select` and `poll` does a linear search across the sockets, which does not scale very well. Then I thought, can I do better, knowing application specific behaviour of the sockets?

For instance, if

- X<sub>n</sub>: the time of arrival of the nth datagram for socket X (for simplicity lets assume time is discrete)
- Pr(X<sub>n</sub> = x<sub>n</sub> | X<sub>n-1</sub> = x<sub>n-1</sub>, X<sub>n-2</sub> = x<sub>n-2</sub> ...): the probability of X<sub>n</sub> = x<sub>n</sub> given the previous arrival times

is known by statistics or assumption or whatever. I could then implement an algorithm that polls sockets in the order of largest probability.

The question is, is this an insane attempt? Does the library `poll`/`select` have some advantage that I can't beat from user space?

**EDIT:** to clarify, I don't mean to duplicate the semantics of `poll` and `select`, I just want a working way of finding at least *a* socket that is ready to receive.
Also, stuff like `epoll` exists and all that, which I think is most likely superior but I want to seek out any possible alternatives first.

Comment: Your link does not state that they do a linear *search*. Obviously there is a linear copy step into and out of the kernel, and there is a linear scan to see which sockets are to be selected/polled, but the actual underlying mechanism is going to be some kind of multiple-semaphore wait, followed by a linear scan of the *now-ready* sockets to map them back into the original data.

Comment: I know `poll` and `select` are multi-platform... but using platform specific calls such as `kqueue` (BDS / macOS) and `epoll` (Linux) makes more sense for performance. For example, both `kqueue` and `epoll` are implemented using kernel level callbacks that register events (instead of polling). So instead of polling a large array of objects twice (both in the kernel and your code), your code is essentially polling on a single object (the event's queue) and than "popping" events from that queue...

Comment: @EJP The linear handling of sockets is actually what I propose to avoid, if the application can only handle a limited amount of sockets at once, or want to distribute the work done in a specific way, scanning everything is pretty meaningless, or so I would think.

Comment: @Myst Yes I do realize their existence, which may ultimately be the way to go 100% of the time, but until I actually find a definitive answer that a custom poll is just dumb, I'll try :)

Comment: @PasserBy , I think that a callback/signaled approach will always perform better than a polling approach. However, signals in user space don't work as well as they do in kernel space. The difference in architecture between `poll`/`select` and `epoll`/`kqueue` is exactly that. You can't write a polling system that will perform better than the `epoll`/`kqueue` design. They are implemented within the kernel using callbacks and accessed in user space using the equivalent of a pipe-queue. How can you beat a design where neither the kernel nor the user poll or iterate over any sockets?

Comment: @PasserBy, if you're hypothesizing only a limited number of sockets in play, then you don't have the problem imputed to `select()` and `poll()` in the first place.  The claim there is that they are slow for managing *large numbers* of I/O channels.

Comment: @JohnBollinger handle as in respond to the sockets at once, a server is unlikely to respond to *all* sockets at once.

Comment: @Myst Why don't you make the argument that doing a complicated poll will still be slow compared to callback based stuff, thus proving this is indeed an insane attempt, as an answer, and I'll likely be happy with it

Comment: @PasserBy, a server with only one network interface will *never* respond to all sockets at once, but that's irrelevant, because it's not what `select()` and `poll()` do.  They tell the server *which* sockets are ready to be serviced.  At this point I'm not sure what you're arguing, however.  You asked whether your idea has merit, and prevailing opinion seems to be not.  If you are determined to disagree then I'm not sure why you asked the question.  Ultimately, the only way really to settle it is to implement your idea and test it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does the library `poll`/`select` have some advantage that I can't beat from user space?

The C library runs in userspace, too, but its `select()` and `poll()` functions almost certainly are wrappers for system calls (but details vary from system to system).  That they wrap single system calls (where in fact they do so) *does* give them a distinct advantage over any scheme involving multiple system calls, such as I imagine would be required for the kind of approach you have in mind.  System calls have high overhead.

All of that is probably moot, however, if you have in mind to duplicate the semantics of `select()` and `poll()`: specifically, that when they return, they provide information on *all* the files that are ready.  In order to do that, they must test or somehow watch *every* specified file, and so, therefore, must your hypothetical replacement.  Since you need to scan every file anyway, it doesn't much matter what order you scan them in; a linear scan is probably an ideal choice because it has very low overhead.

Comment: Put in an edit to clarify, I didn't mean that the semantics must be identical

Comment: Fair enough @PasserBy, but you still have the issue of spreading out the task over multiple system calls vs. doing everything with one, which, as I already said, probably kills you.  Plus, you're now comparing apples and oranges.

Comment: Yes, I am indeed comparing apples and oranges. Given that I specifically said the user knows something the kernel doesn't, it isn't exactly fair is it :) I'm just trying to make sure the cpu is working on something productive instead of finding the work. And yes, I am more convinced this is likely a bad idea the more people talk to me about it